# Zurb Foundation: Block Grid Equal Height Images?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have some images that all have different heights and I'm trying to display them in a block grid with equal heights but I can't figure it out.

I'm thinking that making them background images in a div would be the right way to go but I'm not really sure.

Here is a codepen of basically what's happening. I want the blocks on the same row to be equal.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvGpXa

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-2 data-equalizer">
<li data-equalizer-watch><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></li>
<li data-equalizer-watch><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"</li>
<li data-equalizer-watch><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></li>
<li data-equalizer-watch><img src="http://placehold.it/350x100"></li>
</ul>
```

If anyone could help me out with this problem, that would be amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Several things need to be updated.

The first is that you need to include jQuery. Foundations javascript relies on jQuery so be sure to load it before loading Foundation's javascript.

```
<script src='link_to_jQuery'></script>        
<script src='link_to_foundation_js'></script>
```

The second is that you need to initialize Foundation's js and send the equalizer method some extra parameters.

```
<script>
$(document).foundation({
  equalizer : {
  // Specify if Equalizer should make elements equal height once they become stacked.
  equalize_on_stack: true
  }
});
</script>
```

The data-equalizer is not a css class. It is a data elements and needs to be like this:

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-2" data-equalizer>
```

Here is a working codepen(I added the `panel` class to your `li`s to make it easier to see if everything is working): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdxZBB

Comment: okay, great. but, how do I make it so that the images of different heights fill up the blocks, while also keeping the block sizes equal?

Comment: To make images fill the entire background using css you'll have to set them to be background images for each of the divs. See the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images You'd probably want to use `background-size: cover;` Does that make sense?